# Pydub trim and fade not working correctly

Tags: python, audio, pydub

I have a audio file as mp3. And I want to trim it with fade-in and fade-out. So my code snipped like that:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

files_path = '/Users/User/Desktop/audioFade/audios/'
file_name = '03 Mana'

startMin = 0
startSec = 0

endMin = 0
endSec = 10

# Time to miliseconds
startTime = startMin*60*1000+startSec*1000
endTime = endMin*60*1000+endSec*1000

# Opening file and extracting segment
song = AudioSegment.from_mp3( files_path+file_name+'.mp3' )

extract = song[startTime:endTime]
extract = extract.fade_in(2000)
extract = extract.fade_out(3000)

extract.export( file_name+'-extract.mp3', format="mp3")
```

But extracted file has no any fade-in or fade-out

Why Im getting this type error. How can I solve this? Or is there any alternative package for this process?

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced this issue too - perhaps not ideal if you're using pydub for all your other audio processing, but you can apply fades manually with soundfile and numpy ala [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65048786)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32037813)